# Get the length of video recorded so far (or get accurate start time)

Tags: java, android, video, recording, video-recording

I want to synchronize other sensor data with the video I'm recording, and so I'd like to record "how far am I into the video" when the sensor is triggered. Is there any way to do this? I couldn't find an appropriate method on the MediaRecorder class.

Another solution would be to just get the precise start time of the video recording, but my tests show that the video starts ~1sec after calling mediarecorder.start, but it's not consistent.

Answer (score 0):

You have raised an interesting topic.
If you refer to the documentation in the [developer page](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder.html), the following diagram states the recording is supposed to start when the `start()` method is called.

[image]

Your solution is supposed to be correct albeit there is a lag up to 1 sec. I would do it the same way
I went through the MediaRecorder class methods, the only method that seems to be useful is the callback `setOnInfoListener()`.
Set it and see if you will get some kind of information when the recording starts! I haven't tried it yet though.

Comment: from what I could tell, the InfoListener will only be called when the video has passed a maximum length or size... http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder.html#MEDIA_RECORDER_INFO_MAX_DURATION_REACHED